# Junit testing with two,three dependency classes mocking, stubs. any recommendation for Junit tutorial and examples

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I am new to Junit testing, and i will like to learn about the two,three dependency classes mocking, stubs. any recommendation for Junit tutorial and examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html) you can find a good tutorial that talks about JUnit and Mockito, which is what I like to use to mock dependencies.